How do we achieve the rollback in Azure DevOps CICD pipeline?
We have setup the CICD pipeline in Azure DevOps. We are able to achieve the CICD deployment using this release pipeline. But not able complete rollback concept with this release pipeline. Please suggest ideas for rollback in Azure DevOps CICD Pipeline.

What exactly are you deploying? An App Service, a kubernetes application,...? Depending on what you're doing and how you implemented the pipeline, rolling back could be an extra stage where you run a custom script or task or simply rerun the pipeline using the previous version of the code. Please provide us more details about the pipeline.

What is the destination platform/service of your deployment? It should depend on whether the destination platform/service supports Rollback, not the release pipeline. You should check if the destination platform/service has provided any ways (such as CLI, API or pipeline tasks) to allow you to do Rollback. If the destination platform/service does not support Rollback, you can consider using the previous source version to build and release with a new app version.

Yes, there is a feature in Classic Release pipelines that can be used to automatically rollback to the previously deployed Release for that stage. Classic pipelines have a rigid structure that separates Build from Release, so it's safe to assume that a successful previous release should be restored upon failure.
However, because YAML pipelines have so much more flexibility and can be used for different purposes (CI, CI/CD, CD, Workflows, etc), they cannot take a prescriptive position for rollback.
There are so many options within the industry that it's difficult to say there's a definitive approach. Some options include:

re-run the pipeline from the previous commit
re-run the stage from a previous pipeline
prevent rollback by using a blue/green approach so that blue is tested before it is made live, rollback would involve reverting to green
use a canary approach to test a small percentage of traffic using the new version before rolling it out to everyone. The rollback operation would revert the traffic diversion to the original and abandon the deployment.
turn the feature off using a feature flag
hammer at the problem until it works

Conceptually, YAML CI/CD pipelines support a deployment job that provides scaffolding for different types of rollout operations (runOnce, rolling, canary, etc). You have full control over what happens within that scaffolding:
- stages: build
  ...
- stages: deploy_prod
  jobs:
  - deployment: deploy_prod
    environment: production
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - # deployment steps
        on:
          failure:
          - # trigger remediation actions
          - # report a failure so that we know our new features weren't deployed

For example, if you can safely rollback by re-running this stage from a previous pipeline run, then I would use PowerShell and the Azure DevOps REST API in the failure section to:

query the list of recent successful deployments to obtain the pipeline run
use the update stage endpoint to re-run the stage from that run
log some meaningful message to the end-user to continue with the other pipeline.

If you have approval gates on your stages, the stages will need to be approved before proceeding.
